# remove lines based on value of two columns

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a huge file (my_file.txt) with ~ 8,000,000 lines that looks like this:

```
1   13110   13110   rs540538026 0   NA  -1.33177622457982
1   13116   13116   rs62635286  0   NA  -2.87540758021667
1   13118   13118   rs200579949 0   NA  -2.87540758021667
1   13013178    13013178    rs374183434 0   NA  -2.22383195384362
1   13013178    13013178    rs11122075  0   NA  -1.57404917386838
```

I want to find the duplicates based on the first three columns and then remove the line with a lower value in the 7th columns, the first part I can accomplish with:

```
awk -F"\t" '!seen[$2, $3]++' my_file.txt
```

But I don't know how to do the part about removing the duplicate with a lower value, the desired output would be this one:

```
1   13110   13110   rs540538026 0   NA  -1.33177622457982
1   13116   13116   rs62635286  0   NA  -2.87540758021667
1   13118   13118   rs200579949 0   NA  -2.87540758021667
1   13013178    13013178    rs11122075  0   NA  -1.57404917386838
```

Speed is an issue so I could use awk, sed or another bash command
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '(i=$1 FS $2 FS $3) && !(i in seventh) || seventh[i] < $7 {seventh[i]=$7; all[i]=$0} END {for(i in a) print all[i]}' my_file.txt
1   13013178    13013178    rs11122075  0   NA  -1.57404917386838
1   13116   13116   rs62635286  0   NA  -2.87540758021667
1   13118   13118   rs200579949 0   NA  -2.87540758021667
1   13110   13110   rs540538026 0   NA  -1.33177622457982
```

Thanks to @fedorqui for the advanced indexing. :D

Explained:

```
(i=$1 FS $2 FS $3) && !(i in seventh) || $7 > seventh[i] { # set index to first 3 fields 
                   # AND if index not yet stored in array 
                                      # OR the seventh field is greater than the previous value of the seventh field by the same index:
    seventh[i]=$7                     # new biggest value
    all[i]=$0                         # store that record
} 
END {
    for(i in all)                     # for all stored records of the biggest seventh value
        print all[i]                  # print them
}
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit what the command does @JamesBrown? Thanks for the answer

Comment: `seen` is a bad name for that array. Idiomatically we always use the array name `seen` to represent **just** a set of indices that have been seen, not as an array of counts or max values or anything else. In this case your array name should be `max`.

Comment: Fixed the `seen`.